# UIWebView leak? Can someone confirm?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks, uiwebview

I was leak-testing my current project and I'm stumped. I've been browsing like crazy and tried everything except chicken sacrifice. I just created a tiny toy project app from scratch and I can duplicate the leak in there. So either `UIWebView` has a leak or I'm doing something really silly.

Essentially, it boils down to a `loadRequest:` call to a `UIWebView` object, given an `URLRequest` built from an `NSURL` which references a file URL, for a file in the app bundle, which lives inside a folder that Xcode is including by reference. Phew.

The leak is intermittent but still happens ~75% of the time (in about 20 tests it happened about 15 times). It **only** happens on the device -- this does **not** leak in the simulator. I am testing targeting both iPhone OS 3.1.2 and 3.1.3, on an original (1st Gen) iPod Touch that is using iPhone OS 3.1.3.

To reproduce, just create a project from scratch. Add a `UIWebView` to the `RootViewController`'s .xib, hook it up via `IBOutlet`. In the Finder, create a folder named "html" inside your project's folder. Inside that folder, create a file named "dummy.html" that has the word "Test" in it. (Does *not* need to be valid HTML.) Then add the html folder to your project in Xcode by choosing "Create Folder References for any added folders"

Add the following to `viewDidLoad`

```
NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString* filePath = [[resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"html"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dummy.html"];
NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; // <-- this creates the leak!
[browserView loadRequest:request];
[url release];
```

I've tried everything from setting delegate for the `UIWebView` and implementing `UIWebViewDelegate`, to not setting a delegate in IB, to not setting a delegate in IB and explicitly setting the web view's `delegate` property to nil, to using `alloc`/`init` instead of getting autoreleased `NSURLRequest`s (and/or `NSURL`s)...

I tried the answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826566/memory-leaks-with-uiwebview-and-nsurl-already-spent-several-days-trying-to-solve) (setting the shared URL cache to empty) and that did not help.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Submitted to Apple Radar bug id #7892070

Comment: Apple has said it the leak is not present in the iPhone OS 4.0 beta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgot about this question.

The leak is not present in 4.1. I would assume the same for 4.2.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"WebKitCacheModelPreferenceKey"];
}
```

From http://blog.techno-barje.fr/post/2010/10/04/UIWebView-secrets-part1-memory-leaks-on-xmlhttprequest