# Massive UIWebView Memory Leak

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, memory-leaks, uiwebview

Successive calls to

`[self.webView loadHTMLString:[_detailItem htmlText] baseURL:nil];`

were causing my memory usage to explode on iPad iOS 4.3 (device). Simply commenting out that line fixed the problem, but I need to be able to display HTML content.

The official docs don't mention anything about `UIWebView` retaining/releasing content or caching, nothing at all about its memory management details.

Now, the instance itself is instantiated in a NIB file and all I do is call the method above with new content. Would I have to release/alloc-init `UIWebView` at each request to avoid this issue? Is this a known problem?

I know the problem is not with my code because simply commenting out that line fixes the issue. My objects are deallocated normally. `UIWebView` is to blame.

**UPDATE**

Releasing and reallocating the web view every time did indeed fix the problem. So, heads up for anyone using web view to make consecutive loads: allocate, execute load, release, allocate, ... and you won't have any memory problems.

Comment: Related: [UIWebView leak - Can someone confirm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557964/uiwebview-leak-can-someone-confirm).

Answer (score 0):

Not enough points to comment.

A related post [StackOverflow Reused UiWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311564/reused-uiwebview-showing-previous-loaded-content-for-a-brief-second-on-iphone) quotes an Apple Engineer "Don't reuse UIWebViews, that's not how they were meant to be used."

If you really need to reuse the UIWebView, you can use Java Script.  Something along the lines: [self.definitionWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"setBody(\"%@\");", _detailItem htmlText]];